# Solr create Core which has Array of Json object and Json object similar to elastic search

Tags: json, solr

I want to create a core which has doc as under

```
{
  "dataSet_s": "MYSQL_NEW_W",
  "ruleType_s": "IF_EQUALS_THEN_EQUALS",
  "enable_s": "true",
  "testCaseId_s": "CASE_2",
  "condition": {
    "conClause_s": "IF",
    "conField_s": "ENGINE_RPM",
    "conOperator1_s": "GREATER",
    "conVal1_s": "5000",
    "conVal2_s": "1000"
  },
  "result": [
    {
      "resClause1": "THEN",
      "resField1": "SPEED",
      "resOperator1": "EQUALS",
      "resVal1": "100",
      "resVal2": "200"
     },
     {
      "resClause1": "THEN",
      "resField1": "SPEED",
      "resOperator1": "GREATER",
      "resVal1": "1000",
      "resVal2": "2000"
     }
  ]
}'
```

In elastic search the document has the same structure after inserting, but in Solr when I tried insert after creating a simple core it looks..

```
 {
        "dataSet_s": "MYSQL_NEW_W",
        "ruleType_s": "IF_EQUALS_THEN_EQUALS",
        "enable_s": "true",
        "testCaseId_s": "CASE_2",
        "condition.conClause_s": "IF",
        "condition.conField_s": "ENGINE_RPM",
        "condition.conOperator1_s": "GREATER",
        "condition.conVal1_s": "5000",
        "condition.conVal2_s": "1000",
        "result.resClause1": [
          "THEN",
          "THEN"
        ],
        "result.resField1": [
          "SPEED",
          "SPEED"
        ],
        "result.resOperator1": [
          "EQUALS",
          "GREATER"
        ],
        "result.resVal1": [
          100,
          1000
        ],
        "result.resVal2": [
          200,
          2000
        ],
        "id": "ed0af96b-5127-4686-ae4c-26621b941919",
        "_version_": 1541533921419722800
      }
```

Can we store json Object and Array of Json object in solr similar to Elastic search.

Answer (score 0):

There are two aspects to this:

- Storing original structure
- Indexing it for search

Elasticsearch has that built in, but Solr does it through the configuration with some flexibility. It is described in the Reference Guide under  [indexing custom JSON](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Data+with+Index+Handlers#UploadingDatawithIndexHandlers-TransformingandIndexingCustomJSON). Basically, the original structure goes into **_src_** field. The indexing can happen in several different ways, but default would just dump all content into the **text** field, which is effectively what Elasticsearch does.

It is important to remember that both use Lucene underneath which does not support nested structures. So, both engine do mapping between representation and what Lucene can actually do.

Comment: Ok. There is a Setting JSON Defaults , where we need to put this xml

Comment: It goes into the solrconfig.xml, next to other similar definitions.